# Express a square root form in the result of Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

How I can express a square root for example sqrt(2) in the result of a Matlab computation instead of express the irrational number.
For example:
sqrt(2) the result should be

```
2^(1/2)
```

or

```
sqrt(2)
```

instead of

```
1.4142
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: Using symbolic math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the first two examples on the web page [Symbolic Math in Matlab](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/symbolic_math.html) we see that the way to get what you want is

```
sqrt( sym(2) )
```

which returns

```
ans =
2^(1/2)
```

As the page says,

> The key function in Matlab to create a symbolic representation of data is: sym() or syms if you have multiple symbols to make.

Comment: The mathworks link with similar info: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html